Influence function of quantile functional - I think the standard formula has a mistake
Let $F$ be a cumulative distribution function. Assume a nice situation where $F$ is (absolutely) continuous, strictly increasing, with probability density function $f$. Let $T(F)=F^{-1}(p) = \inf \{ x: F(x) \geq p \}$ be the quantile functional for some $p \in (0,1)$. When $F$ is as assumed, this just takes the unique value $\theta$ such that $F(\theta)=p$.
Recall the influence function is defined as
$L(x) = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+} \frac{T((1-\epsilon)F + \epsilon \delta_x) - T(F)}{\epsilon}  $
The standard formula for the influence function $L(x)$ is, according to several sources
$L(x)=\frac{p-1}{f(\theta)}, x \leq \theta$, $L(x)= \frac{p}{f(\theta)}, x > \theta$, where $\theta=T(F)=F^{-1}(p)$.
I accept this formula when $x<\theta$ or $x>\theta$ based on a simple calculation using $F_\epsilon(T(F_\epsilon))=p$, but question this formula for the boundary case $x=\theta$. I think the standard calculation does not work for the boundary case as $F_\epsilon(T(F_\epsilon))=p$ may not hold.
Let $x=\theta$, $F_\epsilon = (1-\epsilon)F + \epsilon \delta_\theta$. I think that $F_\epsilon(y) < F(\theta)=p$ for all $y<\theta$ and $F_\epsilon(y)>p$ for all $y>\theta$. Thus I think that $F_\epsilon^{-1}(p)=\theta$ ie $T(F_\epsilon)=\theta$. Thus, I claim $L(\theta)=0$.
I can't see any error here, and no matter how the quantile function is defined, I think it should be sensibly defined in this case as $F_\epsilon^{-1}(p)=\theta$, leading to $L(\theta)=0$. If I've made a mistake, please advise.
